# How to complete a district in Ticket to Ride London?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-london

The [rule](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_ln_en_rules_2019-04.pdf) says:

> To complete a District, a player must link each Location with each other Location in that District, in no particular order.

Therefore my understanding is that the white player has successfully completed District 5. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: They have also completed district 1 as well as 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Completing a district means that you would be able to get from any location in the district to any other location in the district by traveling along your trains. Essentially the same as completing Destination cards; but with more than 2 locations on them.